# Python API example can't find the keys/docusign_private_key.txt file

Tags: python, docusignapi

I'm trying to use the Python API example in this page:
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client

But the script can't configure the JWT token because it can't find the keys/docusign_private_key.txt file. Where is this file supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to have obtained a private key from docusign and saved it as "docusign_private_key.txt" on your computer. The example assumes that the file is inside a folder called "keys" which is located in your working directory. For example, you could have a docusign folder on your desktop be your working directory. Then, you could have a key folder which contains the text file. Also make sure your key is saved in PEM format as a lot of people seem to be having issues with that as well. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @santiago. I pressed ADD SECRET KEY and saved in PEM format. The JWT token is generated ok. But I'm getting a Bad Request response.  I'm passing my API Account Id as the user id.  `Bad Request:  <br/>HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '1934c076-2ba8-4d54-b7a0-2adbf1d0bea7', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA1DFE4', 'Date': 'Tue, 07 Aug 2018 12:53:16 GMT', 'Content-Length': '11'})
HTTP response body: b'Bad Request'`

Comment: The above comments refers to a Bad Request when calling api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow().